# What is precisionStep in very simple terms?

Tags: solr, solr4

I tried understanding `precisionStep` at several places but cannot fully understand its concept. So, please explain what it is about, in very simple words.

Comment: @downvoter please be kind enough to state a reason. Is it a very stupid question, may be for experts but not for all :)

Comment: Check "How it works" at [NumericRangeQuery Javadoc](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precisionStep is a count, after how many bits of the indexed value a new term starts. The original value is always indexed in full precision. Precision step of 4 for a 32 bit value(integer) means terms with these bit counts: 
All 32, left 28, left 24, left 20, left 16, left 12, left 8, left 4 bits of the value (total 8 terms/value). A precision step of 26 would index 2 terms: all 32 bits and one single term with the remaining 6 bits from the left.

Comment: Can u please provide an example?